# Is it better to use repository patterns in MVC or default MVC patterns in a Laravel?

Tags: laravel

It happens to me that I was suggested to use repository patterns in MVC for my project. I know it puts some extra security in or project but is there any other benefit of changing the project's structure to repository patterns.

Comment: While this is primarily opinion based, I like using repository patterns so all my queries are in one place and I can test the repositories separately.

Answer (score 0):

Repository pattern gives an abstraction of the data layer. So that before your classes will get something from model - there is layer of repository.

Let's say that repository is agent between your controller (or other classes) and models. It is up to developer if need this kind of layer or not.

In my opinion it is good practice to use repositories. I do not want to make direct operations in models. Repository can have extra functions or overwrite some model functions. Then in your controller you send requests to repository, not to model.

When you work with Symfony Framework, you will see that they implement this Repository Pattern by default.